# I get a blank page when i upload my jsf page to server host

Tags: jsf, tomcat, web.xml

I wrote a simple jsf web app on eclipse. My web app works fine when I run it on tomcat 7 server in eclipse. Now I am in the process of deploying it to a server host name = cheetah.arvixe.com.

to do this I have exported my web app as a war file and have unzipped this war file in the public_html folder of the arvixe server.

When I go to my website on my browswer, i get a blank page. When I look at the page source I see my index.xhtml with the jsf tags. I want to know why my page is not showing. Any ideas?

Here is my index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">


<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/BasicTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">

        <h:form>

            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Name"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText id="userid" value="#{user2.userId }"></h:inputText>

                <h:outputText value="Password"></h:outputText>

                <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{user2.pincode}"
                    required="true"  requiredMessage= "#{vm['loginBean.password']}">
                    <h:messages for="password" style="color:red" />
                </h:inputSecret>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandButton value="Register" action="query_results"></h:commandButton>


        </h:form>

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>


</html>
```

and here is my web.xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Redlancelogin</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

in my web-ing/lib i have the jsf-api.jar and jsf-imp.jar

please tell me why I keep getting a blank page when i deploy to the host server. Thank you in advance!!!!

Comment: Unzip your war file and make sure all the files and jars are there. Try to deploy it in another local environment before deploying it on your real server. By the way, it looks like the application can't find the Faces Servlet. Can you tell which web application server uses your server host: Tomcat, JBoss, GlassFish, etc?

Comment: First step would be to read server's startup logs. If in vain, contact their support.

Comment: My server host uses tomcat 5.5. Are you able to run JSF 2.0 on tomcat 5.5?

Comment: That would require hacks. I'd rather look for another host and be more careful with deciding which to use.